# lambda by-value capture in class member function shows strange behavior

Tags: c++, lambda, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In member function `isLarger`, the function parameter `e` is captured by the lambda by-value. I expect the copy-constructor to be called once, however, the copy-constructor gets called 5 times which I am not able to understand why? On the other hand, when `e` is captured by-reference, the copy-constructor is not called and the behavior is as expected.

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct item{
    item(double price_): price{price_}{}
    item(const item& i){
        this->price = i.price;
        std::cout<<"copy-constructor called\n";
    }
    double price;
};

template<typename T>
class catalog{
public:
    catalog(std::initializer_list<T> it_):it{it_}{}
    bool isLarger(const T& e) const{
        if(it.empty()) return false;
        return(std::find_if(it.cbegin(), it.cend(),
                [e](const T& temp){return e.price<=temp.price;})==it.cend());
        // some more logic
    }
private:
    std::list<T> it;
};

int main(){
    catalog<item> c({item(10),item(20),item(30)});
    item ref(31);
    std::cout<<"***********************\n";
    if(c.isLarger(ref))
        std::cout<<"item is larger than all elements in catalog";
    else
        std::cout<<"item is not larger than all elements in catalog";
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows

```
copy-constructor called
copy-constructor called
copy-constructor called
***********************
copy-constructor called
copy-constructor called
copy-constructor called
copy-constructor called
copy-constructor called
item is larger than all elements in catalog
```

Comment: TL;DR the standard algorithms can make as many copies of your functor as they want

Comment: One time `e` is copied into lambda. Then, then entire lambda is copied (moved, actually) into the parameter of `std::find_if`. The other 3 copies are a mystery.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. That was an eye opener.